# Python multiprocessing gets stuck when passing large array through pipe

Tags: python, multiprocessing, pipe

I'm using multiprocessing in python and try to pass a large numpy array to a subprocess though a pipe. It works well with a small array but hangs for larger arrays without returning an error.

I believe that the pipe is blocked and already read a bit about it but cannot figure out how to solve the problem.

```
def f2(conn, x):
    conn.start()
    data = conn.recv()
    conn.join()

    print(data)
    do_something(x)

    conn.close()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_input = read_data()    # large numpy array
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()

    p = multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8)      
    func = partial(f2, child_conn)

    parent_conn.send(data_input)
    parent_conn.close()

    result = p.map(func, processes)

    p.close()
    p.join()
```

Comment: Why are you trying to mix `Pipe` with `map` here? Your worker doesn't use the `x` it receives, the `x` `map` is passing doesn't exist, etc. You generally want to use a `Pipe` with one or more manually launched `Process`es *or* a `map` on a `Pool`, not both.

Comment: @ShadowRanger: The original program calculates a pool of subprocesses with x as individual input (I will edit my post). Do you mean that I can just pass on my numpy array as an argument of f2()?

Comment: Actually, assuming you're on a system which can `fork` (read: Not Windows), you're probably best off not *passing* the `numpy` array at all. As long as `data_input` is initialized before the workers are forked, it will be mapped in as copy-on-write memory to each child, so they can just access `data_input` in `f2` and it will be a perfect copy of what was in the parent at the moment you called `Process` or `Pool`. Passing it as an argument to `f2` using `Pool.map` would require pickling, transmitting and unpickling the data, where `fork`s "free" copy is much more efficient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ignoring all the other problems in this code (you don't have an `x` to pass to `map`, you don't use the `x` `f2` receives, mixing `Pool.map` with `Pipe` is usually the wrong thing to do), your ultimate problem is the blocking `send` call being performed *before* a worker process is available to read from it.

Assuming you really want to mix `map` with `Pipe`, the solution is to launch the `map` asynchronously *before* beginning the `send`, so there is something on the other side to read from the `Pipe` while the parent is trying to write to it:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_input = read_data()    # large numpy array
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()

    # Use with to avoid needing to explicitly close/join
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as p:
        func = partial(f2, child_conn)

        # Launch async map to ensure workers are running
        future = p.map_async(func, x)

        # Can perform blocking send as workers will consume as you send
        parent_conn.send(data_input)
        parent_conn.close()

        # Now you can wait on the map to complete
        result = future.get()
```

As noted, **this code will not run** due to the issues with `x`, and even if it did, the `Pipe` documentation explicitly warns that two different processes should not be reading from the `Pipe` at the same time.

If you wanted to process the data in bulk in a single worker, you'd just use `Process` and `Pipe`, something like:

```
def f2(conn):
    data = conn.recv()
    conn.close()
    print(data)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    parent_conn, child_conn = Pipe()

    proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=f2, args=(child_conn,))
    proc.start()

    data_input = read_data()    # large numpy array
    parent_conn.send(data_input)
    parent_conn.close()

    proc.join()
```

If you wanted to process each element separately across many workers, you'd just use `Pool` and `map`:

```
def f2(x):
    print(x)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    data_input = read_data()    # large numpy array
    with multiprocessing.Pool(processes=8) as p:   
        result = p.map(f2, data_input)
```